# XPage not displaying correctly in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, xpages

I am having trouble displaying XPages in Firefox.  Looking at the page, I figured it was a CSS issue so I looked at the source.

I noticed this for the CSS

What is going on here?  Other CSS links are similarly corrupted.

The page renders fine in IE 8  but not in FireFox.

Here is a link to the site

https://qacldguide.pnc.com/

You won't be able to login but you should be able to see the issue on the login page.

The server is running 8.5.3.

Update:

Works fine on our Dev server (which is not accessible to the outside world).  We are running the same version of server in Dev and QA.  Could this be a server setting?   My admins are out for the holiday so this one might need to wait but any help here is welcome.

FYI Links still show as
   even in Dev.

Update

Works fine in Prod too
https://cldguide.pnc.com/

Comment: Post the source XML for your theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one of problems is that the first css is detected as mime.

Try to remove css aggregation.

And if you check the Style Editor tab in Firefox and check the first stylesheet
it has no rules detected and if I add an enter after .lotusVersion{margin:2px 1px 2px 40px !important;} 
The site starts to render correct, there is where I should look for the problem.

Comment: Thanks looks like turning off aggregation fixed the issue. Any idea why?  I do have a related issue but I think I will post it as another issue.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that some of your own css files has some problem. But the strange thing is that the error is shown in the IBM Css files. Try adding a enter at the end of all your own css files

Comment: I am beginning  to wonder if it was actually an access issue. I noticed even after implmenting your suggestion things still looked a bit strange in both IE and FF but looked ok after I loggged in.I set the CSS file to public access   and it fixed the problem.  It is all working now so I am not going to go back and mess with it.  Anyway thanks for the help.   Strange it always worked before w/o that public access setting.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I did not have public access set on my CSS.   I am not certian why it worked befoere but that is waht fixed the issue now.